# Ruby on Rails Tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here. I'm looking for some high quality Ruby on Rails tutorials.
By high quality I mean by standards of popular tech tutorial sites.

Examples:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 3):

You can look Code School et RailsCast

- [CodeSchool](http://codeschool.com)
- [Railscast](http://railscasts.com)
- [PeepCode](https://peepcode.com/)
- [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/)

Comment: Thanks! If you come across any other high quality tutorials please let me know =)

Answer (score 2):

Go straight to:

http://railsforzombies.org

Comment: Already finished this one! It was awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

The [official Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) are always useful, and the [Ruby on Rails Screencasts](http://railscasts.com/) from Ryan Bates are excellent.

Comment: I've completed the official rails guide but I have not gone through all of them. I will be doing so in the near future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For an overview of rails 3 have a look at www.tekpub.com, they have a rail3 series which is not free but they do have some free titles.

railguage48

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) is highly recommended.